# Issues with fscanf and fprintf using a structure

Tags: c, struct, printf, scanf

```
int main()
{
   char heading1[30], heading2[30], heading3[30], heading4[30], heading5  [30], heading6[30], heading7[30], heading8[30], heading10[30], heading11[30], heading12[30], heading13[30], heading14[30], heading15[30];
   typedef struct student
   {
      char first[30], last[30];
      float stdnum, asg1, asg2, asg3, asg4, asg5, lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4, lab5, mid, fin;
   }student;

   student std1;
   int x;
   stdinfo=fopen("coursemarks.txt", "r");
   temp=fopen("coursemarks2.txt", "w");
   fscanf(stdinfo, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", heading1, heading2, heading3, heading4, heading5, heading6, heading7, heading8, heading10, heading11, heading12, heading13, heading14, heading15);
   fprintf(temp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", heading1, heading2, heading3, heading4, heading5, heading6, heading7, heading8, heading10, heading11, heading12, heading13, heading14, heading15);//prints the marks and student number in the new file
   while (fscanf(stdinfo, "%d%s%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", & std1.stdnum, std1.last,  std1.first, & std1.asg1, & std1.asg2, & std1.asg3, &std1.asg4, &std1.asg5, &std1.lab1, & std1.lab2, &std1.lab3, &std1.lab4, &std1.lab5 , &std1.mid, & std1.fin)!=EOF)//creates a while statement which keeps scaning aand printing information until the scaned file comes to an end
   {
      printf(temp, "%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", std1.stdnum, std1.last, std1.first, std1.asg1, std1.asg2, std1.asg3, std1.asg4, std1.asg5, std1.lab1,  std1.lab2, std1.lab3, std1.lab4, std1.lab5 , std1.mid,  std1.fin);//prints the marks and student number in the new file
   }
   printf("What is the student number:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.stdnum=x;
   printf("What is the student's last name:\t");
   scanf("%s", & std1.last);
   printf("what is the student's first name?\t");
   scanf("%s", & std1.first);
   printf("What is the first assignment mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.asg1=x;
   printf("What is the second assignment mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.asg2=x;
   printf("What is the third assignment mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.asg3=x;
   printf("What is the fourth assignment mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.asg4=x;
   printf("What is the fifth assignment mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.asg5=x;
   printf("What is the first lab mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.lab1=x;
   printf("What is the second lab mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.lab2=x;
   printf("What is the third lab mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.lab3=x;
   printf("What is the fourth lab mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.lab4=x;
   printf("What is the fifth lab mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.lab5=x;
   printf("What is the midterm mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.mid=x;
   printf("What is the final exam mark:\t");
   scanf("%d", & x);
   std1.fin=x;
   fprintf(temp, "%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", std1.stdnum, std1.first, std1.last, std1.asg1, std1.asg2, std1.asg3, std1.asg4, std1.asg5, std1.lab1,  std1.lab2, std1.lab3, std1.lab4, std1.lab5 , std1.mid,  std1.fin);//prints the marks and student number in the new file
   stdinfo=fopen("coursemarks.txt", "w");
   fclose(stdinfo);
   fclose(temp);
   temp=fopen("coursemarks2", "r");
   fscanf(temp, "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", heading1, heading2, heading3, heading4, heading5, heading6, heading7, heading8, heading10, heading11, heading12, heading13, heading14, heading15);
   fprintf(stdinfo, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", heading1, heading2, heading3, heading4, heading5, heading6, heading7, heading8, heading10, heading11, heading12, heading13, heading14, heading15);//prints the marks and student number in the new file

   while (fscanf(temp, "%d%s%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n", &std1.stdnum, std1.first, std1.last, & std1.asg1, & std1.asg2, & std1.asg3, & std1.asg4, & std1.asg5, & std1.lab1, & std1.lab2, & std1.lab3, & std1.lab4, & std1.lab5 , & std1.mid, & std1.fin)!=EOF)//prints the marks and student number in the new file
   {
      fprintf(stdinfo, "%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n", std1.stdnum, std1.first, std1.last, std1.asg1, std1.asg2, std1.asg3, std1.asg4, std1.asg5, std1.lab1,  std1.lab2, std1.lab3, std1.lab4, std1.lab5 , std1.mid,  std1.fin);//prints the marks and student number in the new file
   }
}
```

I know the problems are based around scanning the file and printing to it, But I don't know why. I know how to print using structures and scan, and I've also used files before. I'm fairly new to programing. I know I could do this with out using a structure and make it work fine, however because im stuck on it I really want to find out what the problem is using the structure type. the starting file has a row of headers, and I know these are scanned correctly, however do not believe they are printing either. all other rows have a student number, a last name and first name, and 12 grades.

Comment: Please, indent your code (and check the preview before post).

Comment: I see couple of places where you can change your code but it will be better if you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use `%f` not `%d` with floats.  Don't take the address of struct members for printf.  It takes arguments by value, not by reference.

Comment: A little hint: turn `.asg*` and `.lab*` fields into arrays (like `float asg[5]` and `float lab[5]`). Not gonna fix your issue, but can make your code a little bit elegant. And also replace `headings1[]`, `headings2[]`, etc, with two-dimensional array, like `headings[15][30]`.

Comment: Sorry, the first while loop should contain an fprintf, not printf, I changed it to see if the fscan was working. This is my first post, I don't know what you mean by indent my post... I thought I had. Ya, %d/%f I should have known not to do. I can see what you mean sam, I will do that.

Comment: Well, all I have done is change to a double array, and that literally fixed everything. I don't know why, but I do care. Like, if you know how that works could you tell me?